Cisco Wireless Access Points have wireless controller hard-coded with cisco-capwap-controller
My network team has a problem. They have installed a second wireless controller for a new physical site. The wireless access points at the second site all connect to the wireless controller at our first site. Nothing connects to the controller at the second site.
The network team believes it's due to a hard-coded entry in the APs' configuration. They say, all Cisco AP's first try to connect to hostname cisco-capwap-controller. If that name resolves to an IP address, and the controller responds, the AP will connect to that controller and no other.
According to our network team, there's no way to remove cisco-capwap-controller from an AP's list of wireless controllers. You can add additional hostnames or IPs, but cisco-capwap-controller will always be first on the list.
For years, our company has had one wireless controller. Our DNS has an entry cisco-capwap-controller.ourcorp.com, that resolves to the controller at our first site. That's why all the company's AP's, no matter their physical location, connect to the first site's controller.
We cannot remove our DNS entry for cisco-capwap-controller.ourcompany.com, or we'd have to reconfigure all the AP's at our first site. We can't round-robin the entry, because that would just randomly split the AP's between the two controllers.
I'm working on setting up split-horizon DNS just for one entry: cisco-capwap-controller.ourcompany.com. When an AP from the first site tries to resolve that host name, it will resolve to the first site's controller. When an AP from the second tries to resolve that name, it will resolve to the second site's controller.
This will solve the problem, but is there a better way to do it? Is cisco-capwap-controller really hard-coded into every Cisco AP? Is there a way to remove that hostname from the list of controllers, or at least move it further down the list?

Could you anycast route the same IP address to both controllers at once?
